# Access variable of ng-if scope in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have an element:

```
<div ng-if="products.length>0">
    <select ng-model="model.newItem"
            ng-options="pr.id + ') ' for pr in products track by pr.id"
            ng-init="model.newItem=products[0]" />
</div>
```

and I tried to access model in controller:

```
$scope.addProduct = function () {
    console.log($scope.model.newItem);
    console.log("/order/products/new/" + $scope.newItem.id);
    $http.post("/order/products/new/" + $scope.newItem.id, null)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.currentOrder = response.data;
                $scope.apply;
            },
            function (errResponse) {
                console.log(errResponse.statusText);
            }
        )
}
```

but model comes undefined. How am i able to acces model of ng-if scope in controller?

Comment: You will need to show your entire code. In your current code block there's no place where you set products on $scope and you're looping through it.

Comment: Would it not give you more control over `model.newItem` if you were setting it from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

A not-so-recommended workaround would be to use ng-show instead of ng-if, thus "hiding" the div instead of "destroying" it. This would preserve $scope.model.newItem

```
<div ng-show="products.length>0"> ... </div>
```

This is just a fast workaround, but can become heavy when that div has too much content, given that hiding it still maintains it on memory.